# Array de input radio no formulário PHP

Tags: php, html

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
for ($n = 0; $n < $totquestoes; $n++) {
    $al = $n + 1;
    $cod = $linha['codprova'];
    $q[] = $linha['questao'];
    $r1[] = $linha['descquestao1'];
    $r2[] = $linha['descquestao2'];
    $r3[] = $linha['descquestao3'];
    $r4[] = $linha['descquestao4'];

    echo '<label class = "control-label">' . $al . 'º) ' . $q[$n] . '</label></br>
        <input type="radio" name="codresp" value="1"> <label class = "control-label">' . $r1[$n] . '</label></br>
        <input type="radio" name="codresp" value="2"> <label class = "control-label">' . $r2[$n] . '</label></br>
        <input type="radio" name="codresp" value="3"> <label class = "control-label">' . $r3[$n] . '</label></br>
        <input type="radio" name="codresp" value="4"> <label class = "control-label">' . $r4[$n] . '</label></br>                          
        ';
}
```

Ele cria as perguntas e as respostas com 4 alternativas no input radio,
Só que preciso alterar o name a cada loop do foor de cada alternativa para poder validar as perguntas e respostas no formulário de validação.

Como posso alterar o name do radio para poder assim receber via POST e validar?

Comment: Você tem alguma informação que seja única de cada pergunta, que relacione a mesma com as respostas? Se tiver é só concatenar os nomes dos inputs com esse valor.

Comment: tenho sim o $cod, tem na pergunta e na resposta, e como faço pra receber no POST?

Comment: Mano, o mais simples, cria um for, dá o nome tipo `input1`, `input2`, etc... Assim vai ser mais fácil pra ti trabalhar. Depois coloca tudo dentro de um Json ou array mesmo, dentro do PHP dá pra transformar em objeto e tu vai poder trabalhar sussa com isso com um foreach. Isso é bom pq vai poder até mesmo colocar mais inputs futuramente sem precisar ficar se preocupando em mexer muito no código. No teu caso, utiliza `codresp1`, `codresp2`, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só usar os `name`'s em forma de array concatenando a variável `$n` do laço como índices:

```
name="codresp['.$n.']"
```

Assim você terá coleções separas de `name`'s para cada grupo de respostas:

```
<label class = "control-label">1º) </label></br>
<input type="radio" name="codresp[0]" value="1"> <label class = "control-label"></label></br>
<input type="radio" name="codresp[0]" value="2"> <label class = "control-label"></label></br>
<input type="radio" name="codresp[0]" value="3"> <label class = "control-label"></label></br>
<input type="radio" name="codresp[0]" value="4"> <label class = "control-label"></label></br>                          

<label class = "control-label">2º) </label></br>
<input type="radio" name="codresp[1]" value="1"> <label class = "control-label"></label></br>
<input type="radio" name="codresp[1]" value="2"> <label class = "control-label"></label></br>
<input type="radio" name="codresp[1]" value="3"> <label class = "control-label"></label></br>
<input type="radio" name="codresp[1]" value="4"> <label class = "control-label"></label>
```

Ao submeter o formulário, irá receber com `$_POST['codresp']` o valores selecionados em forma de array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 // 1ª resposta
    [1] => 4 // 2ª resposta
    [2] => 3 // 3ª resposta
)
```

Onde o índice `[0]` é o valor selecionado da primeira pergunta, o `[1]` da segunda e assim por diante.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente @Sam vlw.

Answer (score 0):

A Resposta do Sam é boa e resolve seu problema, mas com base no seu comentário vou sugerir uma segunda alternativa:

```
for ($n = 0; $n < $totquestoes; $n++) {
    $al = $n + 1;
    $cod = $linha['codprova'];
    $q[] = $linha['questao'];
    $r1[] = $linha['descquestao1'];
    $r2[] = $linha['descquestao2'];
    $r3[] = $linha['descquestao3'];
    $r4[] = $linha['descquestao4'];

    echo '<label class = "control-label">' . $al . 'º) ' . $q[$n] . '</label></br>
        <input type="radio" name="{$cod}" value="1"> <label class = "control-label">' . $r1[$n] . '</label></br>
        <input type="radio" name="{$cod}" value="2"> <label class = "control-label">' . $r2[$n] . '</label></br>
        <input type="radio" name="{$cod}" value="3"> <label class = "control-label">' . $r3[$n] . '</label></br>
        <input type="radio" name="{$cod}" value="4"> <label class = "control-label">' . $r4[$n] . '</label></br>                          
        ';
}
```

tenho sim o $cod, tem na pergunta e na resposta, e como faço pra receber no POST?
use

```
$_POST['cod']
```